# Typescript index union type

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript1.4

I'm working with typescript and I have an object with with fields referred to by both strings and numbers. I know if it is indexed by just strings I can specify the type with

`var object: {[index: string]: number}`

Is there a way to do this that will allow the index to be either a string or a number? I've tried `var object: {[index: string|number]: number}` with no luck.

Comment: I don't think so.. I think the only way is to use `: any`

Comment: @Gustav - you can't use `any`. An index *must* be `string` or `number`.

Answer (score 2):

The following works in the TypeScript playground... essentially, this is the behaviour you are after anyway (so you don't need to use a union type).

```
var object: {[index: string]: number};

// Allowed
object[0] = 1;
object['idx'] = 2;

// Not allowed
object[1] = 'string';
object['other'] = 'string';

// Types inferred as number
var a = object[0];
var b = object['idx'];
```